# android how to initialize botonN[]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm programming in android and introduced me problem 
private Button botonN[]=new Button[10];
how to initialize this? 
botonN[0] =(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton0);
this can not 
as they solve

**CODE**

```
public class Facil extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
private Button botonN[]=new Button[10] ;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facil);
    for (int i = 0; i < botonN.length;botonN[i++].setOnClickListener(this));
    botonN [0]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton0);
    botonN [1]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
    botonN [2]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton2);
    botonN [3]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton3);
    botonN [4]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton4);
    botonN [5]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton5);
    botonN [6]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton6);
    botonN [7]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton7);
    botonN [8]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton8);
    botonN [9]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton9);


    } }

<ImageButton
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:id="@+id/boton0"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:background="@drawable/botonamarillo0"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
```

Comment: is button dynamically added orfrom XML ?

Comment: i need initialize with  findViewById(R.id.);  only

Comment: than you have to set ID also Still i am confusing what you want to do plz say more

Comment: put your code in your question and also XML code properly

Comment: and XML code ? if this button dynamic than where you set ID of button ?

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/boton0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/botonamarillo0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

Comment: i thing you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add button like this.(It's sample):

```
    List<Button> botonN = new ArrayList<Button>();

        for (int i = 0; i < botonN.size(); i++){
        botonN.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.boton0);
        botonN.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
        botonN.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.boton2);
//Add more button
    }
```

After this you can set onclick listener for your button.

**EDIT**
Try this too:

```
for (int index = 0; index < botonN.size(); index++) {
            botonN.get(index).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: cannot resolve method add

Comment: sorry do not know how you could add set onclick listener to buttons 
is equals?

Comment: Is your "cannot resolve method add " problem solved ?

Comment: yes  was a my problem

Comment: wow thanks friend i thought it would solve not the problem

Comment: Did you use Imagebutton?

Comment: yes botonN.add((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.boton0));